# Is $A_{4}\times Z_2\simeq \langle g,h \mid g^{12},h^2,{gh}^{12}, gh=hg\rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Is $A_{4}\times Z_2\simeq \langle g,h \mid g^{12},h^2,(gh)^{12}, gh=hg\rangle$?
In addition, is $\operatorname{Aut}(A_{4}\times Z_2)= \operatorname{Aut}(A_{4})\times \operatorname{Aut}(Z_2$)=$S_{4}\times Z_2$? Also, assume G=$\langle g,h \mid g^{12},h^2,(gh)^{12},gh=hg
\rangle$, what's the automorphism group of G?

As J.P said, the isomorphism doesn't exist.

Comment: By $A_{12}$ do you mean the *alternating group* of even permutations on $\{1, \ldots, 12\}$?

Comment: @  Sammy Black Yes!

Comment: Do you have a group presentation for the alternating group?  I would start there.

Comment: Also, if $h^2 = e$ (your second relation), then writing $gh^{12}$ in the third relation is unnecessary:  $gh^{12} = g(h^2)^6 = ge^6 = ge = g$.

Comment: @Sammy Black Sorry I made a mistake, here I mean $A_4$,not $A_{12}$

Comment: @Sammy Black  Also the relation I mean here is ${{gh}}^{12}$= ${{g}}^{12}h^{12}$

Comment: @Joseph: Are you assuming that $g$ and $h$ commute? $(gh)^{12}$ (which I suppose is what you mean), is not the same as $g^{12}h^{12}$.

Comment: @ Brandon Carter, yes I think you are right,  they can be not commutative

Comment: If you map $g$ to a generator of the cyclic group $Z_{12}$ with $12$ elements, and $h$ to the identity, you see that $Z_{12}$ is a quotient of the group given by the presentation. $A_4\times Z_2$ does not have an element of order $12$...

Comment: @j.p thank you very much, and do you have idea about the automorphism group of G?

Comment: According to the theorem in a link you had in an earlier version of your question the statement about the automorphism group of $A_4\times Z_2$ looked correct. But as $G$ is some other group, you first have to identify it (from the presentation I see only an automorphism exchanging $g$ and $gh$ fixing $h$).

Comment: @j.p, yes, I know the aut of A4xZ2 is right, but I am still struggling to find the G, do you know some tricks to find the group by presentation?

Comment: The group $G$ is an infinite hyperbolic triangle group.

Comment: It is not even clear what a question like "what's the automorphism group of $G$?" means.

Comment: @Derek Holt, I mean Aut(G)

Comment: To answer your latest question, yes, ${\rm Aut}(A_4 \times C_2) \cong S_4 \times C_2$, since both direct factors are characteristic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the triangle group $\langle x,y \mid x^k=x^l=(xy)^m=1 \rangle$ is infinite if and only if $1/k + 1/l + 1/m \le 1$. It is virtually abelian when $1/k + 1/l + 1/m = 1$ and hyperbolic when $1/k + 1/l + 1/m < 1$, which is true in your example. So it is certainly not isomorphic to $A_4 \times C_2$ (which doesn't even have any elements of order $12$).

Comment: Thank you, but I think to the 2 genus surface made by (12,2,3) triangles with 24 edges, it's $\Gamma^{+}$ group is just that.

Comment: Also here maybe I forget to say g and h are commutative

Comment: So you are not asking about the group $\langle g,h \mid g^{12},h^2,(gh)^{12} \rangle$ but about the group $\langle g,h \mid g^{12}=h^2=(gh)^{12}=1, gh=hg \rangle$ ? That's a commutative group of order $24$ isomorphic to $C_{12} \times C_2$.

Comment: On the question of ${\rm Aut}(G)$, I have found assertions that the outer automorphism groups of triangle groups are finite, but I haven't found any more details or references.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I wonder what's the automorphism group of $Z_{12}\times Z_2$?

Comment: How to determine if Z4, Z6 are characteristic subgroup of Z4xZ6?

Comment: That's easy - they are not. But I think you are asking too many new questions in comments.

Comment: Could you tell me how do determine is or not? I really want to compute Aut(Z4xZ6)

Comment: @Joseph: If you want to know the automorphism group of $Z_4\times Z_6$ then you can take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102895/how-can-i-compute-mathrmaut-mathbbz-4-mathbbz-times-mathbbz-6-mathbb

Comment: @j.p.Thank you very much!